How can I preserve Driver links between an add-on and Geometry Nodes?
Blender 4.1 makes it possible to create a Driver between an add-on driven value ("Copy as New Driver") and a Geometry Node value ("Paste Driver") but the link is working only within the context of the .blend file where the Driver has been created. If we import the Geometry Node group into another .blend file, the link is broken and needs to be re-established. I would like to know if there is a way to preserve such a link between the add-on and Geometry Nodes when importing the node group into a new .blend file. I am sharing an example and attaching a .blend file to demonstrate:

Below is an add-on script which defines a single float value into the scene and UI panel. Name the file __init__.py and save it into a folder named "TestGeoNodeLink". Then zip the TestGeoNodeLink folder and install the zip as add-on in Blender.
We can use the add-on Value field to drive the Y scale of a cube using the following geometry node group:

To establish the Driver link, right-click on the Value field of the add-on and select Copy as New Driver. Then right-click on the Scale Y value of the Transform Geometry node and select Paste Driver. Then the Y scale of the cube can be modified changing the Value field of the add-on.
Then, export the geometry node group: Mark it as Asset, save the .blend file. Then create a new Blender project, go File > Append..., select the previous .blend file and append only the geometry node group saved previously (into "Node Group" folder of the .blend file, I named in "Test Scale Y" in the example file). Assign the geometry node group to the default cube and observe: even though the Driver is still there in the Transform Geometry node, it is no longer there in the add-on.
The add-on script:
bl_info = {
    "name": "Test GeoNode Link",
    "description": "Testing communication between add-on and geometry nodes",
    "author": "",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (4, 1, 0),
    "location": "3D Viewport > Sidebar > Test GeoNode Link",
    "category": "3D View"}

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator, Panel

class VIEW3D_PT_TGL_GlobalSettings(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "VIEW3D_PT_TGL_GlobalSettings"
    bl_label = "Global Settings"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Test GeoNode Link"

    @classmethod
    def poll(self,context):
        return True

    def draw(self, context):
        row = self.layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene, "tgl_value")
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_TGL_GlobalSettings)
    bpy.types.Scene.tgl_value = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Value", default=1.0, min=0.0, max=10.0, soft_min=0.0, soft_max=10, precision=2)

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.tgl_value
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_TGL_GlobalSettings)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


Drivers are unreliable in such a way. You also can't put a driver on a modifier and expect it to be there when you add another modifier with the same geonodes tree. Or drivers also disappear when you duplicate some objects e.g. nodes.

Ok thanks, that really sucks! My last hope is to build the geo node tree from Python and add the drivers from Python as well, that should be reliable this way.

I've upload a new version of Copy Nodes Keyframes. An add-on that duplicates any selected nodes without losing its KEYFRAMES, DRIVERS AND LINKS. It has a shortcut to do it. BlenderMarket: Copy Nodes Keyframes Gumroad: Copy Nodes Keyframes CNK LITE: Copy Nodes Keyframes LITE FREE!!! Copy Nodes Keyframes documentation [![Copy Nodes Keyframes](https://i.sstatic.net/eALB4I
